# WebView Load data Overlap

Tags: android

whenever i am load data first time using webView.loadDatawithBaseUrl(My Html content) in android 
but data is overlaping behind picture please share your review to resolve my issue with webviewData overlaping like belove image .

[image]

my html code is ::

String data = String
                                    .format("* {}hr { border: none;  height: 1.5px; color: #D9D9D9; background-color: #D9D9D9; }  p { color:black;  } a { color:%s; text-decoration:none; }**%s**%s%s

---

%s",
                                            HYPERLINKS_COLOR, pic, "100%",
                                            borderColor, objList.get(0).title,
                                            objList.get(0).category,
                                            objList.get(0).time, contentBody);

this.webDetailView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

Comment: looks like the issue is the html, please post the html code